# usepackage with arguments simplify multiple

Tags: package-options

When using multiple packages:

```
\usepackage{A,B,C}
```

if one wants to pass arguments to any one, they have to split it up making it verbose, is there anyway around this?

e.g.,

```
\usepackage{A[a],B,C[q]}
```

rather than having to do

```
\usepackage[a]{A}
\usepackage{B}
\usepackage[q]{C}
```

? It may seem pointless but it's not to me.

Comment: I find the “separate calls” much clearer.

Comment: @egreg I don't.

Comment: @Chieron a lot of people agree with egreg. Consider when you try this then `\usepackage{A[a,aa],B,C[q,aa]}` now you have to protect the inner commas, so you'd need `\usepackage{{A[a,aa]},B,{C[q,aa]}}` is that easier to use? I don't think so.

Comment: @daleif I'm not many people and I disagree with egreg and also, it seems, you. Why do we have to protect the commas? And yes, it does seem easier than writing out 3 separate lines. Just because you don't think something doesn't mean much. Do you know that not everyone in the world is right handed? Yes, it's true! I know you don't believe me!

Comment: If the options of all packages have different names, you can try  passing  them as option of the document class.

Comment: What about `\PassOptionsToPackage`?

Comment: If you *really* want to: `\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\Usepackage#1{\@for\next:=#1\do{\expandafter\usepackage\next}}
\makeatother
\Usepackage{[showframe]{geometry},[svgnames]{xcolor}}
\begin{document}
\section{\textcolor{MistyRose}{hello}}
\end{document}`

Comment: Because the parser used by usepackage iterates over the list essentially looking for commas, so the first one it sees is the one in `A[a,...` which is incomplete if we want to load package A with options a and aa. I'm not going to comment on the rest of your rant.

Comment: Or, factoring in @daleif's comment: `\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\Usepackage#1{\@for\next:=#1\do{\expandafter\usepackage\next}}
\makeatother
\Usepackage{[showframe]{geometry},{[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}}}
\begin{document}
\section{\textcolor{MistyRose}{hello}}
\end{document}` (what a mess...)

Comment: if you want you can always redefine a command like \usepackage to work like this. But an unusual syntax will make it more difficult for you to ask questions - I at least wouldn't like it to have to parse such a homemade syntax in a example document and would ask you to change it back.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. Is there any way to get rid of the extra {}'s? Surely there is a way to get it to parse more simply? probably can be done with a lua function more easily but I see no reason why it has to be overcomplicated with extra junk that is irrelevant.

Comment: It is possible, even without lua, but IMHO not worth the effort. Also I am not an expert on this, but presumably you need to mess around with `\@ifnextchar` and then distinguish various cases. The result will be such a mess that you will want to store it in a package, which you need to load with the `\usepackage` command that you seem to dislike... ;-)

Comment: `\documentclass[a,q]{zzz} \usepackage{A,B,C}` will work in the common case that the option a is only declared in package A.